# Get TCP Flags with Scapy

Tags: python, tcp, packet, packet-capture, scapy

I'm parsing a PCAP file and I need to extract TCP flags (SYN, ACK, PSH, URG, ...).
I'm using the `packet['TCP'].flags` value to obtain all the flags at once.

```
pkts = PcapReader(infile)
for p in pkts:
        F = bin(p['TCP'].flags)
        print F, bin(F), p.summary()
        # manual flags extraction from F
```

Is there a way to obtain a single TCP flag without manually extract it from `packet['TCP'].flags` value?

Comment: Define smarter way? How are you manually doing it already?

Comment: So you're saying the above approach works? What is the issue with the code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Normally, the usual way to handle FLAGS is with a bitmap and bitwise operators. If your `Packet` class doesn't have specific method to test for flags, the best thing you can do IMHO is to:

```
FIN = 0x01
SYN = 0x02
RST = 0x04
PSH = 0x08
ACK = 0x10
URG = 0x20
ECE = 0x40
CWR = 0x80
```

And test them like this:

```
F = p['TCP'].flags    # this should give you an integer
if F & FIN:
    # FIN flag activated
if F & SYN:
    # SYN flag activated
# rest of the flags here
```

Sadly, python doesn't have a `switch` statement to make this more elegant but it doesn't really matter much.

Hope this helps!

Comment: if F & RST:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'LayerFieldsContainer' and 'int' (getting this error)

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `Packet.sprintf()` method:

```
>>> p = IP()/TCP(flags=18)
>>> p.sprintf('%TCP.flags%')
'SA'
```

If you want the "long" names, use a `dict` instead of a long `if`...`elif`... expression (`dict` are often used in Python when you would use a `switch` in other languages):

```
>>> flags = {
    'F': 'FIN',
    'S': 'SYN',
    'R': 'RST',
    'P': 'PSH',
    'A': 'ACK',
    'U': 'URG',
    'E': 'ECE',
    'C': 'CWR',
}
>>> [flags[x] for x in p.sprintf('%TCP.flags%')]
['SYN', 'ACK']
```

Comment: does the 'SA' flag signify an "SYN-ACK" packet?

Comment: Yes it does, each flag has a short (1 letter) and a long (3 letters) representation. When using the short, one would usually write flags together ("SA"), while when using the long, one would use a separator ("-" or "+", so "SYN-ACK" or "SYN+ACK").

Comment: But what is IP()/TCP(flags=18) ? Not able to use this statement as is. Please define any new variables

Answer (score 8):

This also works.

```
if packet[TCP].flags.F:
    print('FIN received')
```

Comment: it probably uses the `__getattr__` semantics
https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderattr/getattr.html

Answer (score 3):

Another option, for the record, which did not exist by the time this question was asked. It works with current Scapy development version (the first release including this change will be 2.4.0; 2.4.0rc* also include it).

You can now use `str()` on the flag value:

```
>>> p = IP()/TCP(flags=18)
>>> p[TCP].flags
<Flag 18 (SA)>
>>> str(p[TCP].flags)
'SA'
```