# How to detect the first SYN packet in the 3-way handshake

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I want to build a program in Python, using Scapy to count how many times SYN packet is received.
How do I find only the first SYN received in the 3-way handshake?

Comment: Scrapy does **not work** on that level: scrapy is on the *application layer*. The SYN packet is on the *transport layer*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So how can i recognize the packet in the transport layer?

Comment: Scapy is not the same as scrapy :-o Just saying.

Comment: @barny I'm using scapy and i know that its possible

Answer (score 0):

You can check the flag manually. Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429674/get-tcp-flags-with-scapy). The flag as 0x02 is what you want.