# IPv6 filter in Scapy

Tags: python, scapy, tcpdump

I am using scapy to sniff a IPv6 packet with a specific source ip /dest ip.

Example:

```
filter1 ="tcp port "+`port`+ " and ip6 host 2001::4 and tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn !=0 and !icmp and !arp and not host "+host_ip

            a= sniff(count =1,filter=filter1,iface=eth)
```

This throws an exception as shown below:
scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: Filter parse error

Answer (score 1):

I've never used scapy, but I noticed in your `filter1` expression that you have:

```
+`port`+
```

... yet you have:

```
+host_ip
```

Maybe you need the back-tiks around the `host_ip`?

If that's not the problem, you can also try to validate capture filters using tools such as [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html), e.g., `tcpdump -d ${filter1}` or [dumpcap](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html), e.g., `dumpcap -d ${filter1}` before attempting to use them in scapy.

Comment: backticks were used for port as python does not allow to concatenate interfer (port being an interger) with string, whereas host ip is a string

Answer (score 1):

For complex filters, scapy allows you the use of a python function as a filter:

```
desiredip = "2001::4"
undesiredip = host_ip

def isMyPacket (pkt):
    if IPv6 in pkt:
        pktip6 = pkt[IPv6]
        if pktip6.src == desiredip or pktip6.dst == desiredip:
            if pktip6.src != undesiredip and pktip6.dst != undesiredip:
                if TCP in pktip6:
                    if pktip6[TCP].flags & 0x02: #Check if it is a SYN
                        return True #If all conditions are met
    return False


a= sniff(count =1,lfilter=isMyPacket,iface=eth)
```

Anyway, you don't need to check whether it is arp or icmp: If it is TCP you know for sure that it is not arp nor icmp.

More about TCP flags in scapy: [Get TCP Flags with Scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429674/get-tcp-flags-with-scapy)